# How to set animation timing in CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation, time

Is there any function or tactic to set a custom animation timing? I am tryng to create a custom timed police flash animation but I have some issues. For example I have 2 colors. Red and blue. I want that blue will flash 1 second and stop flashing and red will start to flashing and when red stop flashing blue starts flashing.

Comment: I answered your question. Please check it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can help you.

```css
.blue {
  animation: bluePoint 2s infinite;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  animation: redPoint 2s infinite;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
@keyframes bluePoint {
  0% {opacity: 1}
  12.5% {opacity: .5}
  25% {opacity: 1}
  37.5% {opacity: .5}
  50% {opacity: 1}
  100% {opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes redPoint {
  0% {opacity: 1}
  50% {opacity: 1}
  62.5% {opacity: .5}
  75% {opacity: 1}
  87.5% {opacity: .5}
  100% {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a 2 second animation. The blue light will flash for the first second (0-50% animation time) and the red light will flash from 50-100% animation time.

To do that use keyframes as in the sample below.

To make the animation continue from start, use the `infinite` syntax;

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

.blue {
  animation: 2s infinite flashblue;
}

.red {
  animation: 2s infinite flashred;
}

@keyframes flashblue {
  0% {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: darkblue;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}

@keyframes flashred {
  0% {
    background-color: salmon;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: salmon;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: firebrick;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: salmon;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```